# ¿Como cambiar el formato de una o varias celdas de Excel en Python?

Tags: python

Me gustaría saber cómo se cambia de un formato a otro en una columna de Excel con Python.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En Python puedes usar la librería [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). El objeto [`Cell`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.cell.cell.html) tiene un atributo llamado [`number_format`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html). En tu caso parece que quieres trabajar con fechas y estos formatos incluidos en la librería te pueden ayudar: [Styles/numbers](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/openpyxl/styles/numbers.html)

Comment: Para modificar el formato de una columna completa harías algo parecido a esto `ws.column_dimensions['A'].number_format = 'h:mm:ss'`. Según la documentación: _Los estilos pueden aplicarse a columnas y filas, pero tenga en cuenta que esto sólo se aplica a las celdas ya creadas (en Excel) después de cerrar el archivo. Si desea aplicar estilos a filas y columnas enteras, deberá aplicar el estilo a cada celda usted mismo._